# call function defined in a file include after this file

Tags: php

Suppose I have following files

```
<?php 
     include 'file_A';
     include 'file_B';
 ?>
```

a function defined `foo()` in `file_B`, is there any way to use it in `file_A` by any means???

actually, I am working in a application where a range of different functions are defined in modules, I want to use these function across the modules without looking where it defined included before or after the file even.

Comment: I would say no, but following your question, maybe I hope not.

Comment: Spider-code, spider-code, does whatever, some spider-code does.  Can it call, a random function, no it can't, because it's interpreted. ... Try having some structure to your modules.  When you generate a call graph and it looks like a hideous spiderweb, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Borealid - Yeah, but we have all been there, out of control of what code was running, yet *responsible*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As PHP is an interpreted language, you cannot do this.

What I would do as a solution is extract the methods you need to share into a `CommonMethods` class or something similar. Make them static if possible.

Then include the CommonMethods file before `file_A` and `file_B`.

I'd spend a little time researching design patterns for PHP before continuing your project. Spaghetti code is **never** a good thing.

Comment: Spaghetti code? Did you say spaghetti code? I like spaghetti. I like ravioli. Can you program in ravioli? Gnocchi? I like Italian food.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Spaghetti code... I haven't heard that term for a very long time

Comment: It's the first thing I think of when PHP is mentioned. Not necessarily due to the language itself, but the programmers I've dealt with who utilize it. I've seen terrible examples of spaghetti code. And not just regular spaghetti, we're talking angel hair.